# android dynamic listview with scroll

Tags: android, listview

I'm creating an android book that use data from database(sqlite) and has six season.
my data is about 1MB and for loading data on listview is slow.I wanna to put a dynamic listview for my project that load 10 item on listview with scrolling each time.
please help me

Comment: what have you done so far for this in code?

Comment: If you want to load 10 items each time, you just need to get 10 data from database and then notify. I think it's mostly depends on your app's logic.

Answer (score 1):

ListView actually keep in memory items only visible for users - check it for better understanding - http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296.

I think you are talking about lazy loading data from sqlite, so just fetch next 20 (or whatever) items when user scrolled to last item.

I recommend you to switch to RecyclerView. Please check [that article](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView) for implementation of endless scrolling with RecyclerView.

Comment: @mohsen1993 I think I cover both cases in my answer. If you still have question, feel free to ask. If no - close your question with marking that answer as a right one.